# Why is the sourcemap invalid when is use UglifyJs?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, uglifyjs

When I run `npm run build` in my react app I get the following warning: `static/js/widget.js contains invalid source map`.

When I remove the UglifyJs settings in my webpack config the build process passes without any warnings.

My Webpack config (only parts which are relevant regarding the sourcemap):

```
// Source maps are resource heavy and can cause out of memory issue for large source files.
const shouldUseSourceMap = process.env.GENERATE_SOURCEMAP !== 'false';

module.exports = {
  // Don't attempt to continue if there are any errors.
  bail: true,
  mode: 'production',
  // We generate sourcemaps in production. This is slow but gives good results.
  // You can exclude the *.map files from the build during deployment.
  devtool: shouldUseSourceMap ? 'source-map' : false,

...


plugins: [
    new UglifyJsPlugin({
      uglifyOptions: {
        sourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap,
        warnings: false,
        compress: {
          comparisons: false
        },
        output: {
          comments: false,
          ascii_only: true
        },
      }
    }),
]
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into the same issue using webpack for vue.js.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue and I figured out that, with Webpack 3 and Ugify I dont see this issue, whereas if I am using Webpack4 the warning is thrown. Trying to dig further. Let me know if you found some solution

Comment: checkout this link https://webpack.js.org/plugins/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/#sourcemap